# How to clean up the useEffect function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Im new to react and started using hooks but I'm receiving warning on my console

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
>   cleanup function

I tried to fix it by defining a variable to check if its unmount or not(saw on another stackoverflow question. But it did not work.

here is my code

```
const Page1 = (props) => {
    const [averageAPICallsPerDay, setAverageAPICallsPerDay] = useState(false);
    const [org, setOrg] = useContext(OrgContext);
    const [catalog, setCatalog] = useContext(CatalogContext);
    const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);

    function getAverageAPICallPerDay() {
        axios.get(`${ANALYTICS_BASEPATH}/${org}/${catalog}/analytics/calls/average`)
            .then(res => setAverageAPICallsPerDay(res.data.data.averageCalls))
            .catch(err => setAverageAPICallsPerDay('No records found'))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDidMount(true);
        getAverageAPICallPerDay()

        return(didMount)
    }, [catalog, org])

    return(
        <Container>   
            <SubContainer>
                <Row>
                    <Col><Card cardTitle="Total API Calls" totalCalls={averageAPICallsPerDay}/></Col>
                </Row>
            </SubContainer>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here might be that you are updating your state from your `then` or `catch` function once your component has been unmounted. I think you can define at the top of your effect a `isCancelled` variable with false, and from your effect return a function that set's it to true, and check that function in your `then` function.. something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isCanceled = false
  function getAverageAPICallPerDay() {
    axios.get(`${ANALYTICS_BASEPATH}/${org}/${catalog}/analytics/calls/average`)
        .then(res => {
          if (!isCanceled) {
            setAverageAPICallsPerDay(res.data.data.averageCalls)
          }
          })
        .catch(err => {
          if (!isCanceled) {
            setAverageAPICallsPerDay('No records found')
          }
        })
  }
  setDidMount(true);
  getAverageAPICallPerDay()

  return () => {
    isCanceled = true
  }
}, [catalog, org])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am replying too late. It might help other devs who come here with same issue. React's useEffect returns a cleanup function. As per my understanding you want to set didmount to false.

useEffect's return can be return as follows:

```
useEffect(()=>{
//side effects 
return ()=>{ setDidmount(false)}
})
```

Note - First time useEffect does not run cleanup. when some state changes after init load and you have written some cleanup function. In that case, second time before updating any state it will run cleanup function